# Не могу получить уведомление waiting_for_capture от Яндекс Кассы

Tags: php, laravel, яндекс-касса

Уже какой день не могу получить уведомление от Яндекс Кассы waiting_for_capture. Работаю с Laravel.

Методы в контроллере:

```
//Метод создания платежа

public function store(Request $request){
   $this->resp = $client->createPayment(
      array(
         'amount' => array(
             'value' => $request->input('amount'),
             'currency' => 'RUB',
          ),
          'confirmation' => array(
             'type' => 'redirect',
             'return_url' => 'https://mysite.ru/check'
          ),
       ),
       $idempotence_key
    );
    $url = $this->resp;
    return redirect()->away($url->confirmation->confirmation_url);
}

//Метод принимающий уведомление от Якдекс Кассы

public function check(Request $request){
   var_dump(json_decode($request));
   die();
}

///////// В роутере вызываю методом get//////////////
Route::get('/check', 'YandexKassaContorller@check');
```

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

Answer (score 0):

**return_url**  - это адрес странички куда будет перенаправлен пользователь после оплаты.

Уведомления касса шлёт на url который вы указываете в настройках магазина на сайте яндекс кассы. Параметры для платежей -> **Адрес для уведомлений**

Отлавливать оповещения от яндекса нужно вот таким способом json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")